# PDO Sql query with join 2 tables returns one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, inner-join

I'm trying to make a drop down menu. Menu is taking values from mysql table.
I'm using 2 tables, 1st is for main menu item, and 2nd is pages and nested with parent categories in menu. So my menu must looks like this;

```
<ul>
<li>MAIN MENU - 1 <!-- from menu table -->
   <ul>
       <li>SUB MENU - 1 - 1</li><!-- from sayfalar table -->
   </ul>
</li>
<li>MAIN MENU - 2 <!-- from menu table -->
   <ul>
       <li>SUB MENU - 2-1</li><!-- from sayfalar table -->
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I have 2 table in my mysql database named: 'menu'=parent and 'sayfalar'=children.

**sayfalar Table Structure** :

```
sayfa_id | sayfa_foto | sayfa_ad_dil1 | sayfa_ad_dil2 | sayfa_detay_dil1 | sayfa_detay_dil2 | ust_menu_id
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        | NULL       | HAKKIMIZDA    | ABOUT US      | DENEME           | LOREM IPSUM      | 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**menu Table Structure**

```
menu_id | menu_ad_dil1 | menu_ad_dil2 | menu_order
--------------------------------------------------
1       | ANASAYFA     | HOMEPAGE     | 1
--------------------------------------------------
2       | KURUMSAL     | CORPORATE    | 2
--------------------------------------------------
3       | BLA BLA      | BLA BLA      | 3
--------------------------------------------------
4       | LOREM        | IPSUM        | 4
--------------------------------------------------
5       | İLETİŞİM     | CONTACT      | 5
--------------------------------------------------
```

And mysql query with PDO looks like;

```
<?php
// PDO Sorgu Hazırla
$query = $db->prepare
('SELECT menu.*, sayfalar.ust_menu_id, sayfalar.sayfa_id
    FROM menu
    INNER JOIN sayfalar
ON menu.menu_id = sayfalar.ust_menu_id ORDER BY `menu`.`menu_order` ASC');
// PDO Sorguyu Çalıştır
$query->execute();
?>
```

and echoing like below;

```
<?php
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
    echo '<li class="pi"><a href="link.php?i='.$row->menu_id.'"><span>'.$row->menu_ad_dil2.'</span></a>';
        echo '<ul class="pi-submenu pi-has-border pi-items-have-borders pi-has-shadow pi-submenu-dark">';
            echo '<li class="pi"><a href="urun-detay.php?i='.$row->sayfa_id.'"><span>'.$row->menu_ad_dil2.'</span></a></li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    echo '</li>';
    }
?>
```

Unfourtunately, it's returning only 1 row. i have 5 parent menu item in my menu table as seen above. Any help will greatly appricated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
// PDO Sorgu Hazırla
$query = $db->prepare
('SELECT distinct menu.*, sayfalar.ust_menu_id, sayfalar.sayfa_id
    FROM menu
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sayfalar
ON menu.menu_id = sayfalar.ust_menu_id ORDER BY `menu`.`menu_order` ASC');
// PDO Sorguyu Çalıştır
$query->execute();
?>
```

Comment: It works perfectly but parent menu items showing them children for each other;

Comment: try the edited code the problem with your original query is the on condition in inner join checks id's of both tables and output's only the id's present in both the tables.Since your syfalar table had only id 1 you got only one result.Left outer join returns all rows for the table in the left with no condition matching and returns rows only that matches the condition for the table in right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check when you change between "menu" table names, because right now you're treating every row in the result as its own parent/child entry. e.g. you want something (in pseudo-code):

```
$previous = null;

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
   if ($row['menu.name'] != $previous) {
      got a "new" menu entry
      echo "<ul><li>', $row['menu.name'], '<ul>';
      $previous = $row['menu.name']; // save for next iteration
   }
   echo '<li>', $sayfalar, '</li>';
}
```

Comment: I'm too lazy to understanding previous = null. we have an if statement for if menu item hasn't got sub menu?

Comment: +1 For show me a path to understand what is going on :)